# `ls` behavior on EACCES error for /root and /root/some-rubbish

Tags: directory, ls, exit-status

I'm trying to code a clone of the `ls` command as part of a school exercise. I'm wondering why the following output is displayed by `ls`:

```
$> ls -- -test_dir  /root /root/some-rubbish
ls: /root/some-rubbish: Permission denied
-test_dir:
test.txt

/root:
ls: root: Permission denied
```

Specifically, I've noticed that when the searched folder has more than one "part", that is, when is it has at least one `/` between two alphanumerical parts, like `that/folder`, then `EACCES` errors get displayed at the top. Otherwise, they are displayed in alphabetical order like any other listed directory.

I'm currently testing this on OSX 10.8, if that makes any difference.

I hope the above is clear enough. If not, I'll try to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial set of error messages is produced when `ls` does an `lstat()` of each of its arguments. An argument that doesn't exist or that can't be accessed because one or more of its parent directories is non-searchable (doesn't have the appropriate 'x' bit on) are some examples where `lstat()` will fail and an error message will be produced.

Objects in the argument list for which `lstat()` fails are removed from the argument list.

After this, each argument has its name printed, and (unless you've given `ls` the `-d` option) each argument that is a directory has its name, a ':', and its contents printed. If a directory is not searchable, `ls` will output an error message at this point. `/root` is most likely lstat-able but not searchable by non-root users.